# Android: Issue with runing the app in background

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to make my GPS run in the background, so it can provide me with new information about where I am while I am doing something else.

But every-time I run the application it crashes. The error wants me to use  `Looper.prepare()`, but how can I do that with my GPS?

```
public class LocationLoggerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

Location location;

String towers;
static final int uniqueID = 1394885;
Thread runner;
boolean keepRunning;

public LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    keepRunning = true;

    runner = new Thread(null, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startGps();
        }
    });
    runner.start();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // this service will run until we stop it

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    String hey1 = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    String hey2 = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

    Toast.makeText(this,
            "TEST onLocationChanged:" + "Lat: " + hey1 + "Long: " + hey2,

            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

}

public void startGps() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            2000, 0, this);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    String hey1 = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    String hey2 = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

    Toast.makeText(this, "StartGPS: Lat: " + hey1 + "Long: " + hey2,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


}
```

My manifest has the following permissions as shown below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />

<service
            android:name="LocationLoggerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="LocationLoggerService" />
```

I am getting this error in the logcat as shown below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-819
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:209)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:209)
at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:687)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:512)
at com.example.rememberforme.LocationLoggerService.startGps(LocationLoggerService.java:81)
at com.example.rememberforme.LocationLoggerService$1.run(LocationLoggerService.java:38)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: What was the error in LogCat?

Comment: The logcat has nothing to do with your app - please enclose proper logcat in which shows your app is running! FWIW, that is not even an error - that is coming from native binary NDK compiled GPS handler...

Comment: OP: Please re-edit your question and not put in 1 liner logcats within these comments... be sure to include as many lines as possible so that ***we*** can deduce where the errors are!

Comment: I just updated my question @t0mm13b

Comment: Problem is that the calling of the `Toast` within `startGPS` is in a thread which is the cause of the crash. You need to implement a mechanism such as `runOnUiThread` which takes a `Runnable` as an argument, in which the UI can make the Toast within their own thread, or implement a handler (created from UI Thread) and pass the message to the handler from within the thread `startGps` to pop up a  `Toast` notification.

Comment: Hmm can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Heey,

I see that you are missing the onCommandStart method for your service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    //this service will run until we stop it

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And did you add all the permissions needed in your manifest file?
I'm not sure which one you need but one/or more of these for will do it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
```

Comment: I just updated my code. But i am getting a new problem.  Looper.prepare()